# Postman return null values in response

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I have created a simple Java spring boot API to add employees. I want to check to employee add endpoint. When I try with it in postman I am getting null values in response.

But its status is `200` and id auto-increment is also working fine.

[image]

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/vi")
public class EmplyeeController {
  @PostMapping("/add")
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
       return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, 
Long>{}
```

How can I solve this? This is my first spring boot application. I wish your help to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Please show your Controller

Comment: there is problem in your  api method  in controller. check your controller or show it us

Comment: Did you try to log or put a debugger to check your response entity returned from your spring boot app? It should be among the first steps to triage or solve these :)

Comment: @B_Osipiuk I have updated the question with the controller.

Comment: @Bahtiyar I have updated with my controller

Comment: When you  save data with entity , it just return id  that inserted . not return other info. for other Info to return , you have set  them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correct your payload as Spring bind your payload with Entity when it should have the same attribute but In your case you are using _ "underscore" in your payload and in Entity you are using camelCase so the solution would be updating the post payload and then it will work.

```
{
   "emailAddress":"",
   "firstName":"",
   "lastName":""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i was also facing the same issue, check in application.properties where spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/product, weather its mapped to exact schema name in mysql db, i.e case sensitive, previously i have given as /Product

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem solved by adding @RequestBody

```
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        Employee employee1 = employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employee1,HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically we want to provide the fields  as same as entity and check once if there is spaces in the postman like

Ex: " empname":"sudha" (wrong) -> if u will give like this in that time also will get nulls
"empname":"sudha" (right)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **lombok.jar** manually into STS
And then add
**@Data** annotation just above entity class name